# Internet disconnecting while downloading a large file

Tags: internet, disconnect

Every time I leave my computer on to download a game for Steam about an hour later the internet disconnects. But the "Ethernet 1" still comes up on the internet options.

```
-00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R7 Graphics]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri HDMI/DP Audio Controller
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1424
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1425
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1424
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port
00:03.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1424
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:10.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 16)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6400 Series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
03:00.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Yuan Yuan Enterprise Co., Ltd. Device 0380
```

Comment: How "big" the file is? Maybe it's the remote server that got some issue. Have you tried to download another big file from another site? (You can try to download Ubuntu iso files)

Comment: There's really not enough information in your question to guess what the issue is. Does it say something like "Ethernet 1" and then right below that "Disconnect"? Or does it say something like "Ethernet Networks" and then right below that "disconnected" and below that "Ethernet 1"? It would also help if you could open a terminal and run `sudo lspci` and edit your question to include the results from that. (That will let us know what ethernet hardware you have, which could help if it is a driver issue). What kind of internet is this? DSL? Cable? I'm assuming a wired connection to a modem/router

Comment: Does the internet disconnect when not downloading a "big file" (4 GB?) and you are simply surfing for an hour instead? When you say "Ethernet 1" still comes up on internet options do you mean you are really still connected to the internet? Are you using Chrome or Firefox? I'm sorry but as is your question is unclear to me.

Comment: Ok, it looks like you have a realtek ethernet card. Here's a question: once it disconnects while downloading, what do you have to do to get back online again? Also, I'm trying to understand what the network manager menu shows when it first disconnects. Next time you have the problem, can you open the screenshot program, and set the "grab after a delay of x seconds", click take screenshot, and then open the network menu and wait for it to screenshot it? (And then edit your question with that image?)

Comment: Another idea that might help us find the problem: install the "mtr" (my traceroute) program by running `sudo apt-get install mtr`, and then start it from the terminal by running `mtr 8.8.8.8` while you are running your download. Once the computer disconnects, take a screenshot of the mtr window and post that -- it may tell us what part of the network is breaking. Is the problem just that the download gets interrupted, or does all internet access break (as in you can browse the internet after the hour)?